# Django >= 3.1 and is_ajax

Tags: django, ajax

`HttpRequest.is_ajax()` is deprecated starting with version 3.1.

I want to return html if the page is requested from a browser and as `JsonResponse` if called from javascript or programmatically.

I am seeking guidance on how to do that.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax

Comment: its is deprecated, but not *yet removed*.

Comment: @JPG I come from the future in the year 2023. is_ajax is removed now in django 4. and finally, robots rule the world!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Check `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header

```
def sample_view(request):
    is_ajax = request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

From the [Release Notes of 3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/#id2)

> The `HttpRequest.is_ajax()` method is deprecated as it relied on a jQuery-specific way of signifying AJAX calls, while current usage tends to use the JavaScript Fetch API. Depending on your use case, you can either write your own AJAX detection method, or use the new `HttpRequest.accepts()` method if your code depends on the client Accept HTTP header.

Comment: Just a note to many other solutions here. Adding `request.accepts("application/json")` doesn't seem right ot me. This header might be send for any regular non-ajax request, for example in for of `Accepts: */*`. Browsers are not forced to request a specific MIME type, although they might suggest if that matters. But on server side it usually doesn't matter.

Answer (score 8):

Funny thing -- the quoted deprecation blurb only gets you halfway there. There's no indication of *how* you "use the new `HttpRequest.accepts` method" to replace `HttpRequest.is_ajax` -- not in the deprecation text, nor the documentation, nor the release notes.

So, here it is: `if request.accepts("application/json")`

(At least that's what worked for me.)

Comment: Take care that if your request will accept `*/*`, this test may be wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of:

```
if request.is_ajax():
```

Helped me:

```
if request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
```

Comment: Adding reference to orig conversation on Django group: https://groups.google.com/g/django-users/c/5x-qF0Q5Xi8

Answer (score 3):

Combining the suggestions works for our use cases...

```
def is_ajax(request: django.http.request.HttpRequest) -> bool:
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63629935
    """
    return (
        request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
        or request.accepts("application/json")
    )
```

And then replace all instances of `request.is_ajax()` with `is_ajax(request)`.

Comment: The part `or request.accepts("application/json")` shouldn't be there, check comment on accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to check **HttpRequest.headers**?
**HttpRequest.is_ajax()** depends on  **HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH** header.
so you can check this header, if it is true it would be AJAX other wise it would be a request from a browser.

```
HttpRequest.headers['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']
```

Answer (score 0):

I did what arakkal-abu said but I also added
`'X-Requested-With'` header with the same value
ie. `'XMLHttpRequest'`

to my request and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to import this at the top

```
import re
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.conf.urls import handler404
```

You can have this inside your function/method to determine if from browser or ajax call

```
    requested_html = re.search(r'^text/html', request.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT'))
    if requested_html:
        # requested from browser, do as per your wish
    # ajax call. Returning as per wish 
    return JsonResponse({
        'detail': _('Requested API URL not found')
    }, status=404, safe=False)
```

## Explanation

If you request to load a page from a browser, you would see in the network tab under the requested headers of that request, `text/html` is at the beginning of `requested headers`.
[image]

However, if you are making an ajax call from the browser, the `requested headers` has `*/*` in the beginning. If you attach

```
Accept: application/json
```

in the header, then requested headers become this
[image]

From this, you can understand how the accept header is different in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

## your_app.middleware.py

```py
class AjaxMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        def is_ajax(self) -> bool:
            return (
                request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
                or request.accepts("application/json")
            )
        
        request.is_ajax = is_ajax.__get__(request)
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

## settings.py

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'your_app.middleware.AjaxMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).